# Struts 1 bean tag inside HTML quotes

Tags: html, struts

Here is my code:

```
<html:text name="rptData" property="emailAddress" onblur="checkIfEmpty('<bean:write name="rptData" property="status" />' , this.id)" />
```

This is nested inside a **logic:iterate** tag. What i need to do, is to pass value of 'status' to the javascript **checkIfEmpty** method. But i guess there is some error in the quotes. It is not working properly. Please anyone guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok after doing some research i found out the answer.

if i have some code like this:

```
<html:text styleId="emailAddress+<%=statusC.toString() %>" name="rptData" property="emailAddress" />
```

its output is as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="emailAddress" value="abc@gmail.com" id="emailAddress+<%=statusC.toString() %>" />
```

but if i use

```
<html:text styleId="<%=statusC.toString() %>" name="rptData" property="emailAddress" />
```

the output is:

```
<input type="text" name="emailAddress" value="abc@gmail.com" id="Approved" />
```

That means without string concatenation the output is correct. i.e. only using

```
styleId="<%=statusC.toString() %>"
```

rather then

```
styleId="emailAddress + <%=statusC.toString() %>"
```

or even

```
styleId="emailAddress" + <%=statusC.toString() %> - This results in an error, though
```

yeilds correct output.

So the workaround is to first intialize a complete java String in a scriplet then use it inside the styleId tag.

```
<% String emailId =  "emailAddress" + statusC.toString()  ;%>
<html:text styleId="<%=emailId%>" name="rptData" property="newEmailAddress" />
```

It will work fine. Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest custom tags like that, period, and it's unfortunate most of the answers imply you can, because that represents a fundamental misunderstanding of JSP.

Ideally, you wouldn't use the `<logic:iterate>` tag, as its use is not recommended when you have JSTL available: when JSTL and Struts 1 tag functionality overlaps, use the JSTL option. Then use standard JSP EL to access the variable.

```
<c:forEach items="listOfThings" var="current">
  ...
  <html:text ... onblur="checkIfEmpty('${rptData.status}', ${current.id})" ...
  ...
```

In this example I also assumed that `this` was supposed to refer to the current iteration object, defined in the `<c:forEach>` tag.

Comment: My clients requirement was to use struts tag. Thanks for the answer though ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try adding some escape characters while using double quotes inside double quotes like in your case it would be some like:

```
onblur="checkIfEmpty('<bean:write name=\"rptData\" property=\"status\" />' , this.id)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html:text name="rptData" property="emailAddress" onblur="checkIfEmpty('<bean:write name=\'rptData\' property=\'status\' />' , this.id)" />
```